# How to avoid being overwhelmed when doing code review?

Tags: code-reviews

I'm pretty new to code review, and I feel often overwhelmed by incoming changes.

I mean when there are serious code changes, coming from several developers I tend to accept everything without reviewing the whole, especially when I have lots of stuff to finish up.

What are the techniques to help in being efficient in this area ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plan code review for the first thing in the morning before you do any of your other projects. If you have several developers passing their code to you, then it will likely take you a few hours. It helps if the developer is there explaining why he did something the way he did. You should try to dedicate the time to the code review. If you are feeling overwhelmed, then you should go to your manager and tell him you need to lighten your workload because you can't handle it. Don't feel pressure to finish other projects because you are being overloaded.

Answer (score 2):

For doing code reviews, you should be an expert in that code base. So you should have a fair idea of critical parts of the code. For example, details of logging may not be as important as say a new data structure being introduced. So if you have to skim some parts, skim over the less critical parts.

In languages like C or C++, starting with header file changes give an idea of significant changes. The key is data structure changes. New data structures added, new fields added to existing data structures etc. You can ask the implementor for details of data structural changes.

Also being an expert in the code base, you should have a fair idea of newbie mistakes that can happen. You can even document such easily made mistakes and use it as a check list. Others also will find it useful. Maybe it can be part of an internal wiki.

Comment: How to separate critical changes from cosmetic one when you receive several lot of 10 to 20 files ? Scanning the changes already takes precious time...

Comment: @Guillaume - The author(s) of the change should document the reason somethign was done until the point it is accepted or review by you.  This allows you quickly find cosmetic changes or functional changes.

Answer (score 2):

Are there code review guidelines in your workplace? How closely are you conforming to them? How is code review distributed - are you - by merit of being new/more popular/less popular/less unpopular etc - getting more than average code review? Is it possible that more of it is starting to come to you because you're seen as more lenient?

My policy would be to timetable your day for a while - set time aside for code review tasks in particular and try not to exceed it. Schedule it if you like, and keep to that schedule.

Comment: No guideline, no tools, no distribution: it is more a good practice set up by developers. Main idea is to proof reading incoming changes.

Comment: @Guillaume: I think it's time you formalize your code reviewing process and run it by your team and your management. Everyone should be aware of what is being looked at, how it will be done and how it benefits everyone, which can justify the amount of time it takes to do.

Answer (score 1):

Code reviews can be done in many ways, ranging from a simple reading of what one of your developers has written to a formal review where you (and a board of peers) are being guided through the changes.

While I believe strongly in an occasional formal code review, it sounds like you're going for an informal code review when code is checked in, is that correct?

Given that scenario, it has been mentioned before that there are some best practices and human factors that you can use to avoid being overwhelmed:

- Define a specific time to do code
  review, such as first thing in the
  morning, for x hours. Preferably not
  more than 2 hours at a time, as it
  can get tiring very fast and your
  efficiency wanes quickly.
- If you have too much work, tell your
  boss about the time you have set
  aside for code review and have them
  adjust the workload and estimates
  accordingly.

Human factors aside, do you currently use tools to assist in your code review? Some tools and best practices could include:

- A diff tool, showing you clearly what
  changes have been made from one
  version to another. Eclipse even has
  a compare view built in that makes
  reviewing changes very easy.
- Enforce comments in version control.
  Make sure everyone mentions on what
  they have worked on and gives an
  overview of their changes so that you
  do not waste time looking elsewhere.
- Usage of code review tools. I recall
  Fogbugz had Kiln (but I have not used
  it in a long time) and Atlassian has
  Crucible, which can assist in
  structuring and distributing code
  review duties. A quick search online
  might help you find a tool to help
  you. However, remember that suck
  tools take time to learn and to adapt
  to, and will most likely not save you
  any time at first, especially if you
  are in the middle of a project.